# Moving Assets from one Repo to another, git commit history?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-fork

I am moving only section of an apps repo from one to another but was wondering if its possible to keep commit history like in fork on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.  You can probably use `git filter-branch`.  It's a powerful (but also fairly complicated) command.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Exactly how to do it depends on exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. how the new repo's directory structure will look relative to the old one).